# How to enable MAP drive on remote computer session

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, network-drive, microsoft-file-explorer, new-psdrive

I've been scratching my head for a long.
I've two Windows servers joined to Domain and DFS is installed.
So when I'm trying to create a MAP drive remotely from server1 to server2 code is not getting an error and it is showing the drive is created but when I log on to server2 to check, it is not showing the mapped drive.
I've tried many methods but it is not working out for me when I execute the script manually to the remote server it gets created only while remote execution I'm facing the issue.
This is the code I'm using

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $SecondaryServer -ScriptBlock { 
Register-PSSessionConfiguration -Name Demo -RunAsCredential 'abc.local\Administrator' -Force }

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $SecondaryServer -ScriptBlock {

 New-PSDrive -Persist -Name "T" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "\\abc.local\Demo1" -ErrorAction stop
 } -ConfigurationName Demo
```

The above code is not generating any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using -Scope Global.
And why using  separate invoke session ! , single session would work.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $SecondaryServer -ScriptBlock { 
Register-PSSessionConfiguration -Name Demo -RunAsCredential 'abc.local\Administrator' -Force
New-PSDrive -Persist -Name "T" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "\\abc.local\Demo1" -ErrorAction stop -Scope Global
 } -ConfigurationName Demo
```

Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive?view=powershell-7.2&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-6

```
New-PSDrive -Persist -Name "X" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "\\Server01\Public" -Scope Global
```

Comment: I've also used scope global in the script still the issue is the same.
and the reason why I'm using a separate session is that when I'm using the command in a single session it is getting an Access denied error which is a Double hop error. so I've created seperate session

Comment: I think map drive remotely need the cred supplied in plain text
check this <https://stefanos.cloud/kb/how-to-configure-mapped-network-drives-with-different-credentials-using-powershell/>

Comment: I can confirm that `-Persistent -Scope Global` has no effect. Trying two powershell's, the other shell doesn't see the new drive. Contrary to all that is said in various MS documents. Even tried refreshing env variables etc.